# Three level ListView with dynamic data

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollview, listadapter

I’m trying to implement three level list views where only the top level is required to be scrollable. Example of the UI is as below:
List view 1: List of houses  : scrollable
List view 2: List of rooms in houses : Not scrollable
List view 3: List of windows in the rooms : Not scrollable
Important thing is that the data I fill up needs to be dynamic. So the number of items in the list view 2 and 3 can be changed.
[image]

I don’t want list view 2 and 3 as scrollable as they are not going to have too many items, and I want them to be displayed always. Therefore, only top level list view is required to be scrollable. 
I tried with 3 level expandable list views but I really don’t need expandable list views as they increase the number of clicks to view all the information at one time.

I tried is to add ListView within ListView and adding adapter to add items in the low level list views. But its not working. It displays only top level list view but the child list view is not displayed at all.

Is there any way to add ListView within ListView as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not much item in listview 2 & 3 then do not use listview for level 2,3.
Use a listview for 1, LinearLayout for 2 & 3 and add textView dynamically to those layouts.
Put 2,3 layout to another linear layout and align it to bottom ... so remaining place above those view will be covered by listview.
Comment if my answer is not clear or you need more explanation.